# Count variable not stopping while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

For a class I wrote a function that checks if a number is prime(called is_prime). That works swell, but I need to write a function that can print out the first 'n' prime numbers. I have it working, but the code runs through every prime number, appends it to a list, and prints out the first 'n'.

Here's the actual code.

```
def is_prime(n):
  primed = False
  if n > 1:
    for i in range(2,n):
      if n % i == 0:
        break
    else:
      primed = True
  else:
    primed = False
  return primed
is_prime(997)



def first_primes(n):
  count = 0
  primo = []
  while count <= (n):
    for i in range(2, 1001):
      if is_prime(i) == True:
        primo.append(i)
        count +=1
  return primo
first_primes(4)
```

My while loop isn't working within the function. I have a count variable, but it doesn't stop the loop when it is equal to 'n'.

I have it with the positional argument cause I've tried moving the indent in, changing the order of the count variable being changed, and still have no idea what to do.

Comment: Infecting in the first code sample is incorrect.

Comment: `while count <= (n)` The while condition is checked at the **beginning** of each loop iteration.  If the condition becomes false in the middle of an iteration, the loop does not automatically exit.  So the inner `for i in range(2, 1001)` loop runs to its full extent.

Comment: Also, consider `if n % i == 0: return True`.

Comment: this actually works perfectly fine.  it finds all the primes upto `1001`, because this is what is set in the `for loop`...

Comment: @D.L It doesn't stop after finding the first 4 primes, which was the intent.

Comment: @JohnGordon,  agreed.  i posted a full working answer with an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

The count needs to be checked inside the for loop.

```py
def first_primes(n):
  count = 0
  primo = []

  for i in range(2, 1001):
    if count == n:
      break
    if is_prime(i) == True:
      primo.append(i)
      count +=1
  return primo
```

Also you can reduce the number of validation in is_prime by checking till half of the n rather than all the way to n.

```py
def is_prime(n):
  primed = False
  if n > 1:
    for i in range(2,n//2+1):
      if n % i == 0:
        break
    else:
      primed = True
  else:
    primed = False
  return primed
```

Answer (score 0):

basically remove the while loop in the second function. everything is covered in the for loop, which can be exited with a `break` statement.

i just change the second function like this:

```py
def main():
    x = first_primes(4)
    print(x)
    return

    
def is_prime(n):
  primed = False
  if n > 1:
    for i in range(2,n):
      if n % i == 0:
        break
    else:
      primed = True
  else:
    primed = False
  return primed




def first_primes(n):
    primes = []
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        if is_prime(i):
           primes.append(i)
           counter += 1
        if counter >= n:
           break
    return primes


# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

returns:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```